# A question of Probability using Law of Total Probabiliity

Tags: probability

Pedro wants to work at Google. He finds out that out of the people who apply, the probability
of getting a phone interview is 0.1. Once you get a phone interview, the probability of getting
a site interview is 0.25, and once you get a site interview, your probability of getting a job
offer is 0.3. What is the probability of Pedro getting a job offer from Google?

I called probability of phone interview P(A) = 0.1, probability of site interview after given phone interview P(B|A) = 0.25, probability of job offer after site interview P(C|B) = 0.3, and Pedro getting job offer P(C).

Solving for P(C),

P(C) = P(C|B)P(B) + P(C|B^c)P(B^c)

P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A^c)P(A^c) = 0.25(0.1) + X (0.9)

How do I solve for X?

Comment: What does "...a phone interview is 0:1" mean?

Comment: Sorry, i meant 0.1. The post is revised.

Comment: I think the assumption is that $P(B \mid A^c) = 0$ and $P(C \mid B^c) = 0$. (If you don't have a phone interview, you can't get an on-site interview; if you don't have an on-site interview, you can't get a job offer.)

Answer (score 1):

You are overly complicating the problem.  The probability of getting a job interview is simply the product of the three probabilities given.  $P(C)=0.1\times 0.25\times 0.3=0.0075$.